# Refresh UIView with paging animation

Tags: iphone, paging

I have a UIView that has controls built based off a date.  I want to flick to change the date and refresh the UIView with an animation like the paging animation.  Is that possible?  I do not want to create multiple copies of my UIView because it is already close to exceeding memory.  2 copies of my UIView would definitely crash the phone.  Does anybody have any suggestions?  Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tested it, you should be able to use the same instance of the UIView that would generate a 'flip' or whatever animation using the same UIView as the underlying view and the overlying view.

I've stumbled into this accidentally, trying to get some animations working.